# cp -L vs. cp -H

Tags: linux, command-line, cp, options, coreutils

**Problem**

When copying files with `cp -H` or `cp -L`, I get the same results:

```
$ ls -l fileA
  fileA -> fileB
$ cp fileA somewhere/ -H
$ ls -l somewhere/
  fileA     # fileA is a copy of fileB, only renamed, with same properties!
```

[This answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/593196/cp-h-vs-cp-l-what-is-a-command-line-symbolic-link) describes both options as similar UNLESS used in combination with `-R`. Not for me. Soft- as hardlinked files become renamed copies of the files they point to at the source.

### **Question**:

What is the proper use of `cp -H` and `cp -L`? Is this the expected behavior?

**My attempt to solve**:
`man cp` tells me quite the same for both options, but `info cp`'s *wording* makes it even more confusing for me. Maybe one can help me break this down a bit:

> `-H`
> If a command line argument specifies a symbolic link, then **copy the file it points to rather than the symbolic link** itself. However, **copy (preserving its nature) any symbolic link** that is encountered via recursive traversal.

This sounds like a contradiction to me: I guess that »*a symbolic link's nature*« is that it points somewhere…

> `-L, --dereference`
> Follow symbolic links when copying from them. With this option, `cp` cannot create a symbolic link. For example, a symlink (to regular file) in the source tree will be copied to a regular file in the destination tree.

I do know that a symlink isn't a regular file, but… I admit I'm overchallenged with this explanation here.

Comment: Run `info cp`, search for `-R`.  It says `Copy directories recursively.`  But you are testing with non-directories.  The difference is about what's *inside* the directories you are copying, not the command line arguments.

Comment: @Mikel I've tried with copying the content of directories and copying the directories with content themselves and got quite the same results. Also: I sat quite a long time in front of `info cp` and tried hard to figure out what the *choice of words* on this option actually means &ndash; and which this posting is about. The posting also contains the actual wording from `info cp` - thus I must have at least opened it… ;)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

With symlinks, tools have two things they can do:

1. Treat the symlink as a symlink ("preserving its nature"), or
2. Treat the symlink as the type of file that it points to.

Saying that `-H` "preserves its nature" is not a contradiction.  Consider the alternative.  If you use `-L`, any symlinks `cp` finds will be opened, and their contents copied to the target file name.  So the source was a symlink, but its copy is not a symlink.  So it "lost its nature as a symlink".

Consider

```
$ mkdir subdir
$ echo "some contents" > subdir/file
$ ln -s file subdir/link

# definition of "list", the abbreviated ls -l output used below
$ list() { ls -l "$@" | \
    awk '$0 !~ /^total/ { printf "%s %s\t%s %s %s\n", $1, $5, $9, $10, $11 }' ; }

$ list subdir
-rw-rw-r-- 14   file  
lrwxrwxrwx 4    link -> file

$ cp -rH subdir subdir-with-H
$ list subdir-with-H
-rw-rw-r-- 14   file  
lrwxrwxrwx 4    link -> file

$ cp -rL subdir subdir-with-L
$ list subdir-with-L
-rw-rw-r-- 14   file  
-rw-rw-r-- 14   link
```

Comment: Great answer—I love the way you illustrate what the options do. It doesn't quite answer *my* question, which is about copying symlinks to sibling directories, but you've made it obvious how I can do a quick experiment to find out. 

Comment: Ah, turns out what I really wanted to know was this: http://superuser.com/a/138594/219388

Answer (score 28):

The difference in behavior between `-L` and `-H` comes when `-r` is specified as well.  `cp` won't create symlinks in subdirectories with `-L -r` but it will if you use `-H -r`.

Comment: cp: the -H, -L, and -P options may not be specified with the -r option.

Comment: Yes,  I think you mean `-RH`  and `-RL` (capital R), using `-r` give the same result as if `-P` were set.